# PostgreSQL select query with where clause 'COLUMN_1 is null' hangs

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Recently we restored PostgreSQL database from the backup which was created without stopping database (I know this was very wrong and now we are paying the price). The backup was simple database directory backup.
Now we noticed that when we execute

```
select *
from table
where COLUMN_1 is null
```

query in one of our tables the query just hangs (freezes) and never finishes. Other queries on the same table run fine and `distinct(COLUMN_1)` returns all the values. The same query runs correctly on the other column `COLUMN_2 is null`. It seems there is something wrong with that one column.

How can I repair such possibly damaged table?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are using and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (format text) select ...`** as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Why would it be wrong to create a backup on a live database? The problem is the method, a copy from the directory while the database is active: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-file.html

Comment: Because I forgot to do that "The database server must be shut down in order to get a usable backup." (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-file.html)

Comment: @polis: you can use `pg_basebackup` for that or `pg_dump` - no need to shut down the server

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it is easier to restore than backing up with simple tar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `vacuum full` and it solved my problem. The query now executes with `is null` clause on that table.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the whole database with `pg_dump` and restore it **to a new cluster**. If that works, it will get rid of all data corruption.

If that fails, you should hire a specialist.

If you attach to the hanging backend with a debugger, you can investigate what it is doing (if you are familiar with the source).

Comment: What if I manually create `TABLE_2` with the same structure as `TABLE` and insert all the data from `TABLE`? After that I would drop `TABLE` and rename `TABLE_2` to `TABLE`?

Comment: There could be corruption elsewhere, for example in the system catalogs.